# How to format a list to rows with certain number of items?

Tags: python, formatting, output

I'm having issues on formatting a list to a formatted output that each row contains five elements but I am stuck.

```
words = ["letter", "good", "course", "land", "car", "tea", "speaker",\
         "music", "length", "apple", "cash", "floor", "dance", "rice",\
         "bow", "peach", "cook", "hot", "none", "word", "happy", "apple",\
         "monitor", "light", "access"]
```

Output:

```
letter good course land car
tea speaker music length apple
cash floor dance rice bow
peach cook hot none word
happy apple monitor light access
```

Comment: Did you want to print list items the same as output?

Comment: See the `grouper` recipe in the `intertools` recipes section of the documentation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> for i in range(0, len(words), 5):
...     print ' '.join(words[i:(i+5)])
... 
letter good course land car
tea speaker music length apple
cash floor dance rice bow
peach cook hot none word
happy apple monitor light access
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension

```
num=5
[' '.join(words[i:i+num]) for i in range(0,len(words),num)]
```

Can also use [chunked](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) but might have to install more_itertools first

```
from more_itertools import chunked
list(chunked(words, 5))
```